# How do I change the color of a label with a button? Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash-builder

This is an example of the code I have.
When the mobile application opens, you can type your desired colour (E.g. #811fb4 for a purple-ish colour), and when you click the button it should change the label colour. 
However lbl1.color does not work. Any ideas?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Custom Colour">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public var customColourChosen:String;

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
            customColourChosen = txtInput1.text;
            lbl1.color = customColourChosen; // <------ //
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:Label id="lbl1" x="144" y="104" fontSize="36" text="Label"/>
<s:TextInput id="txtInput1" x="50" y="138"/>
<s:Button x="124" y="212" label="Button" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:View>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by 'does not work'?  Does your code report an error?  Does it apparently do nothing?  Does something else happen?

Comment: Errors - 1119: Access of possibly undefined property color through a reference with static type spark.components:Label.

I recognize that this is telling me that I can't change a label via .color, so is there a different method? I've tried CSS, but I can't set a custom colour, only preset ones I've chosen. e.g. .redText{color: #d62728;} .purpleText{#811fb4}
I'd like to be able to choose the colour from an Input field instead.

Comment: To be honest, I've never programmed with Flash before, so I can't help you there.  Once you have >10k rep, you gain the ability to 'review' first questions asked by new users. That's how I saw your question.  Now that you've clarified what you mean by 'does not work', hopefully there'll be some people who know ActionScript better than I do who will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lbl1.setStyle('color', 0xff0000);
```

this way you can even use purple I think.. :)

Comment: lbl1.setStyle("color", customColourChosen);

That worked perfectly! Thanks csomakk!